# MessageBox type casting to int

Tags: c#, casting, .net-4.5

Decompiler changed simple `MessageBox` code:

```
MessageBox.Show("msg");
```

To this one:

```
int num = (int) MessageBox.Show("msg");
```

Both works perfectly. What does this type casting mean?

Comment: Show(..) returns a DialogResult, and enum and for that - an integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From C# language specification:

> 6.2.2 Explicit enumeration conversions
>
> The explicit enumeration conversions are:
>
> ·         From sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong,
>   char, float, double, or decimal to any enum-type.
>
> ·         From any enum-type to sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint,
>   long, ulong, char, float, double, or decimal.
>
> ·         From any enum-type to any other enum-type.

In particular, your sample contains explicit conversion from `DialogResult` to `int`. But others type from the list above are allowed too, regardless of underlying enum type.

Answer (score 0):

`MessageBox.Show()` returns `DialogResult` value which is `enum` type so this casting returns you underlying type of the enumeration elements(default is `int` ) casted to `int`

Comment: "This casting returns you underlying type of the enumeration elements" - wrong. This casting returns `int`, because there's a casting to `int`, not because underlying type of enum is `int`. E.g., this would be correct too: `long num = (long)MessageBox.Show("msg")`.

Comment: yes, I understand that, poor choice of words. Thank you for correction.